# Unicode selection from other font

Tags: characters

### How can i choose the `char"EB40` also from other font and for every chapter separately?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newfontface\cmaiusc[LetterSpace=40,WordSpace=2,RawFeature={+swsh,+dlig}]{lmromancaps10-regular.otf}


\newcommand{\Chapter}[4][]{%
   \chapter[\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax#2\else#1\fi]{%
%     \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=6in]{#4}}\\
     #2,\\\large #3\\\char"EB40}
   \begin{center}
     \textit{\cmaiusc capitolo\ \roman{chapter}.}
   \end{center}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
   {\centering\bfseries\huge}%
   {}%
   {-40pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}


\begin{document}
\Chapter{Analysis mathematica}{principia.}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: U+EB40 is in the Private Use Area, so you can't rely on it printing the same in different fonts.

Comment: @egreg i'm sorry, i am explained bad, the EB40 is an example i do not want that character in the specific, but i would to be able to choose any type of character from any type of font for every chapter separately

Comment: Just add an argument.

Comment: @egreg that is? what argument do you mean? for use un character from another font in math i use `\setmathfont[range=\int]{lmmath-regular.otf}`for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\Chapter}[5][]{%
   \chapter[\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax#2\else#1\fi]{%
%     \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=6in]{#4}}\\
     #2,\\\large #3\\{#5}}
   \begin{center}
     \textit{\cmaiusc capitolo\ \roman{chapter}.}
   \end{center}
}
```

Then

```
\Chapter{Analysis mathematica}{principia.}{}{\somefont\char"EB40}
```