# Including letters from other fonts

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

Nowadays, book printers mix different fonts. Aa example of this is Springer, which writes in Times New Roman but takes letters g, v and greek psi (I don't know if more) from `computer modern` (i think).

How can I do the same? Hoe can import a single letter from another family font?

The closest question I have found is [Unicode selection from other font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/unicode-selection-from-other-font) but I don't know understand anything, and import symbols from other packages seems me not be valid for this case.

SOME EXAMPLES:

[image]

from Hussemoller's *Fibre bundles* book.
[image]

from A. O. Barut, R. Raczka *Theory of group representations and applications*, Polish Scientific Publishers distribution by Ars Polona (1980).

EDIT.

Talking yesterday with @cfr I notice I must make two changes:

1.- Certainly, I was thinking about use these import glyphs only in math mode. However, thinking better later, I realize that Springer also uses the ''imported'' glyphs in theorem-like environments (see the 'v' oth Theorem 3.2).

2.- When I post this question I was sure they import glyphs from another family fonts (some people in the [typography.guru](https://typography.guru/) forum confirmed me that). However, some days later I discovered [this PDF](http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/DanielRhatigan_Dissertation.pdf), shows that, at least in the case of Times New Roman, there was extra glyphs **similar** to other fonts. I haven't found the same for Barut's book yet, but it seesm me reasonable to think something similar happens and they don't import extra characters, but they font has extra glyphs.

Comment: Really? Can you show an example?

Comment: See my edits @egreg

Comment: Possibly related:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know that question, but the import symbol there was from a package. Here is a letter. I thought it would be different... Maybe someone can clarify it.

Comment: Maybe page 8 of [this pdf](http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/DanielRhatigan_Dissertation.pdf) is useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, you can do this in math mode with `\setmathfont[range=` ,,,,  For example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mitv,\mitnu}]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
Text mode: \textit{vν}.

Math mode: \( \symit{vν} \).
\end{document}
```

[image: Font Sample]

For a bit of explanation, the `\mit*` macros are Unicode characters from the mathematical alphanumeric code blocks defined in Unicode, and `\symit` explicitly selects mathematical italic symbols.  You could also write `\mitv\mitnu`.

That this does not work if you type `$v$` should probably be considered a bug, or at least a limitation, in `unicode-math` (as of v0.8n).

Some OpenType fonts select alternative shapes for letters such as *g*, *v*, *w* and *z* with character variants, stylistic sets or alternatives.  For example, Stix Two Math changes from a rounded *v* to a pointed *v* that’s more similar to the Greek letter *ν* if you select its stylistic set 3.

In text mode, you can declare a `\newfontfamily` using `fontspec` and switch to it.  For example: `\DeclareRobustCommand\textnu{{\greekfamily ^^^^03bd}}`.  The `newunicodechar` and `ucharclasses` packages might help if you want to be able to type in ν and have it work automatically.  For example, `\newunicodechar{ν}{\textnu}`.

In a legacy NFSS document, compatible with PDFTeX, you could declare a new math alphabet and add new commands (You might name them something like `\varv` and `\varnu`, or `\mathalt{v}`) that load from that math alphabet.  You can also `\renewcommand\nu`.  Some font packages, notably `newtxmath`, give you package options to replace particular glyphs.  To hand-roll this yourself so that you can just write `$v$` in your document would take more work, but you’d probably want a virtual font.

Answer (score 0):

It is a partial satisfactory answer.

The solution to get something similar to Husemoler's book it is enoguh to consider the `varg` option in the `newtxmath` package. It is a partial solution by two reasons:

1.- Because the italic ''z'' isn't like ''*z*'', but i has... a curve? I don't know the exact term, bu you know.

2.- Binary and relation symbols like '\subset', '\cap' '\in'... are different. In fact, these springer symbols are closer to the `matha` otion of the `mathabx package` than others.

In any case, springer books use Times 4-line Mathematics Series 569 and some variants of that.

Regarding Barut's book, I can't say anything unfortunately.

More avdanced and complete answers are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer the question even partially? What do you mean 'it is enough to consider the `varg` option ...'?

Comment: The `varg`option provides you the math characters of g, v and w, as well as the italic greek letters.

Comment: You don't say that in your answer. But, anyway, are you actually only talking about *maths*?

Comment: Yes yes only math. I'll sorry.

Comment: Could you please edit your question in that case? Maths is very different  from text - the way fonts are used and configured differs radically.

Comment: @cfr: I have just edited my question. Thinking later, I notice that actually I want to include imported glyphs also in text. I explain the reason in the edit. I apologize for the confusion.