# Get Times 4-Line Mathematics Series 569 in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, metafont

This question is related to my own question [Including letters from other fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411587/including-letters-from-other-fonts)

Reading on the web, I found [this pdf](http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/DanielRhatigan_Dissertation.pdf). In page 8, it shows a figure with the main characters of  Times 4-Line Mathematics Series 569, a method to print professional math books before computers. It is exactly the characters Springer used until a pair of years (now it seems his books are printed in 'standard' `Times New Roman`).

My question is: is there a `package` which reproduces exactly this symbols? I mean, a package thought specifically to get these symbols in `LaTeX` (or `LuaTeX`or similar).

Thanks

EDIT

I add some pictures from this page.

[image]

[image]

Math relations are similar to the symbols of `mathabx`but I think they are not equals.

**Remark**

Note that I asking for this symbols in particular. In fact, I'm asking for a `package`. My question doesn't have anything in common with other questions, as it is suggested. I'm not searching or identifying anything.

Comment: Which symbols are you asking about? Can you include a screenshot of what you are interested in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @MichaelFraiman See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "4-line mathematics fonts" were specific to the monotype  hot-metal
typesetter.  this system has not been implemented by any electronic system
to the best of my knowledge, nor is it likely to be.

that said, the stix fonts were largely modeled after the monotype times
fonts.  the match is not perfect, but an attempt was made to include
everything that was present in the monotype collection.  (there are also
some other problems, that i won't go into, at least partly because i am
not able to access my library and records at present; i was the person
who compiled the list of symbols for the stix project and presented the
material to uinicode.)

the mtpro fonts (commercial) are also based on times, but the collection
is not as complete as what was available from monotype.  however, again,
i can't give details; i haven't used the mtpro fonts myself.

Comment: I must confess I didn't know anything about Stix project, but I completely agree with it. Fonts were designed many years ago, I cannot understand why they are not free. On the other hand, in my opinion `Stix` `package` seems very similar to `mathptmx`. What is the difference between both?

Comment: @Dog_69 -- the rationale for the stix project was to make mathematics natively available on the web, not just by sharing pdf files.  compatibility with tex was part of the plan, but not the most important part.

Comment: @Dog_69 You might also be interested in Khaled Hosny’s XITS and XITS Math, which are based on version one of STIX.