# Problem with scale of imported glyphs

Tags: fonts, mtpro, math-fonts, newtxmath

Traying to obtain the [Times 4-Line Mathematics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411702/get-times-4-line-mathematics-series-569-in-latex) used in old math books of Springer (and many other scientific textbooks) I downloaded the `mtpro2 lite` package. However, this package doesn't include a `varg` option, like `newtxmath`, as far as I know.

So, following [Egreg's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414182/import-varepsilon-34-from-nwtxmia-tfm-font) [and](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341299/change-only-one-character-in-latex-template), I have imported the glyphs `varg`, `varv` and `varw` to my document.

The problem is that it seems they are quite smaller than the `mtpro2` fonts:

[image]

The following image corresponds to the Springer's book of Morris W Hirsch *Differential Topology*:

[image]

Certaily, the glyph looks different, but the main problem I see is that the `\varg` and especially `\varv` seem quite smaller; in my opinion the $x$ is quite taller.

Do you know a way to correct that? I thought in using the package `newtxmath` instead of `mtpro2` and import the `z` glyph (with the upright base). The problem is that I would have to change also the italic z in normal text.

Here I attach the `mwe`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}    % set Helvetica as the sans-serif font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}      % set Times as the default text font
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

%var letters
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar\font=127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
  <-> ntxmia
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
  <-> txbmia
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxmia}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxmia}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varg}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varv}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varw}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{52}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`g=\varg}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`w=\varw}


\begin{document}

\[
gxv \qquad \{(x,g(x)):x\in U\} \qquad v(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance and happy new year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to provide a scale factor while loading a font by inserting `s * [<factor>]` (or just `[<factor>]`) in the fifth argument of `\DeclareFontShape`.
This is documented in the [fntguide](https://ctan.org/pkg/fntguide) (section 4).

I don't think I've got much more to say about this, so I'll just include an example. I'm using a factor 1.5 below, just for the purpose of illustration/comedic effect, and I've commented out the line loading `mtpro2` because I don't have this font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}    % set Helvetica as the sans-serif font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}      % set Times as the default text font

%% I don't have this font:
% \usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

%var letters
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar\font=127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
  <-> s * [1.5] ntxmia
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
  <-> s * [1.5] txbmia
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxmia}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxmia}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varg}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varv}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varw}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{52}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`g=\varg}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`w=\varw}

\begin{document}

\[
    gxv \qquad \{(x,g(x)):x\in U\} \qquad v(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

#### Edit:

Here's a little demonstration to show that this works in subscripts and at different font sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar\font=127}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{<-> s * [1.5] ntxmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{<-> s * [1.5] txbmia}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxmia}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxmia}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varg}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varv}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varw}{\mathord}{ntxmia}{52}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`g=\varg}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`w=\varw}

\begin{document}

{\tiny gxv, $gxv_{gxv}$}

gxv, $gxv_{gxv}$

{\Huge gxv, $gxv_{gxv}$}

{\fontsize{60}{72}\selectfont gxv,$gxv_{gxv}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that (or something similar). But then the size kept constant, it didn't change in footnotes for example. I don't know if your solution behaves like that.

Comment: @Dog_69: This should also work in footnotes and subscripts etc. It is also how the `scaled=0.92` option you supplied to `helvet` works.

Comment: @Circumscribe +1 for now :-)

Comment: @Circumscribe my tried was more basic. I just replaced `<->` by `<12>`, which is much simpler than your solution.

Comment: @Dog_69: If you use `<12>` instead of `<->` that means that the font will only be available at 12pt. So 12pt versions of these characters would *always* be used, no matter what size was actually requested. With `<-> s * [1.2]` or `<-> [1.2]` all sizes are available, but they're just scaled up by a factor 1.2.

Comment: @Circumscribe I know. But I didn't notice the difference with your answer at first sight. I realized later. Your solution works very well, as your edit shows. If I'm not wrong, the bounty offered by KJO has already finished, so I'll accept your answer.